# phpmyadmin user hostname not localhost for XAMPP development and hosting on webserver

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm currently working on a website. I'm developing with XAMPP and the website is hosted @strato.de. Therefore I need to set the hostname/servername to "rdbms.strato.de" when connecting to the database in the script through PDO. I also have no ability to change this is any way. However, with this code I'm not able to connect my local database anymore. The user is set to the same username and password, the database is also named the as on my hosted webserver. I also tried different variations for the hostname "localhost", "rdbms.strato.de", "%".

Is there any way to adjust the hostname for the user in my local phpmyadmin or to match the localhost to the specific hostname I need to connect when hosting on my webserver?

Code:

```
// Database connection
$servername = "rdbms.strato.de";  // Strato
//$servername = "localhost";        // Localhost
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname"; // of course real username, password and dbname is not displayed here

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: "localhost " is your computer, unless you played with the hosts file of your OS. So, it does not make any sense to point to localhost, in order to connect your registrar database. As much as I recall PHP, your syntax seems correct, and should work given the fact that you are entering the right host address ($servername). Would you give us the exception getMessage() that is returned by your failed connection?

Comment: just to clarify. This code is working on the website. But it is not when I want to test it locally on my computer to develop. I just do not want edit the code every time in every file when I switch between the development and hosting. Unfortunately there is no real failure message: "Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out"

Comment: Well, it is impossible to say for sure what's going on from the code alone, which is correct. It has to come from the server side (your local xampp installation), and more specifically the MySQL service. Is it on? Is it configured to allow all connections, from all users? Isn't it restricted to the phpmyadmin user? This is where you must look into to solve your issue: MySQL access rights.